# SQL Server: select over several tables / conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join

Okay, I'm relatively new to the more advanced uses of SQL Server.

I have several tables that I need to gather informations from, and several of these tables links to other tables where I need a specific information. As a result, I just want one row with all the information, preferential named with aliases.

For example:

`Tab_Transcoders`:

```
ID, VideoCamID, InputStreamID, OutputStreamID.
```

where `InputStream` links to another table where I need the row of the matching `ID`, where in this row are other ID's (e.g. `StreamType_ID` that belongs to a third table containing `ID_StreamType` and `Description` etc.)

Same with `OutputStreamID`, same with `VideoCamID`.

In the end, I need a row containing for example:

```
ID, VideoCamID, InputStreamID, InputStreamType, InputStreamTypeDesc, 
OutputStreamID, OutputStreamType, OutputStreamDesc, VideoCamID, etc. etc. etc.
```

It is important for me that I can set aliases, as for example `InputStreamID` & `OutputStreamID` links to the same table where all my Streams are listed (with IP's, Descs..)

I can accomplish this with doing like 100 `SELECT`S & `SUBSELECT`S, but I don't think that's an appropriate way.

I read some informations about things like `CURSOR, UNION, FETCH, JOIN` etc. etc.. but I don't know which one I have to use for my purpose.

eli

Comment: It sounds like you need to read up on `JOIN`s: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like the following....

```
Select 
      t.ID,
      t.VideoCamID, 
      i.InputStreamID, 
      is.StreamType as InputStreamType, 
      is.StreamDesc as InputStreamDesc,
      o.OutputStreamID, 
      os.StreamType as OutputStreamType,
      os.StreamDesc as OutputStreamDesc,
      v.VideoCamID

from 
     Tab_Transcoders t
     inner join InputStreams i on i.InputStreamID=t.InputStreamId
     inner join Streams is on is.StreamId=i.StreamId
     inner join OutputStreams o on o.OutputStreamId=t.OutputStreamId
     inner join Streams os on os.StreamID=o.StreamId
     inner join VideoCams v on v.VideoCamId=t.VideoCamID
```

Comment: I'm not done writing my 500000 lines query, but it seems your suggestion did the trick. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If there is a defined relationship between your tables, then Use Join. 
e.g Customer Order

Order will have customer Id

```
Select Order.ID,Order.Quantity, Order.CustomerId, Customer.FullName, Customer.Address
From Orders Order
Join
Customer
On
Order.CustomerId = Customer.CustomerId
```

First start by getting data from two tables using the join and then if it works as per your requirement, add another required table in the join.

Read about SQl JOINS.. It is fairly simple.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend reading you some of the articles around CTE aka Common Table Expression.

Refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx.

Apart from this never use subqueries. Try to use inner join / any other join if possible.